# To need access static public IP from internal IP over 4G for server usage (AWS?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

**Pre-amble**

Got an exchange server and other machines running on a physical host.
I have a stack of public IP addresses and the firewall allows various ports through to the various services.
We have just moved offices and there is no internet (yet) at the new office. This is being delayed because of the lockdown.

The physical machine and its associated services are still at the old office making use of the internet there.

I am getting a wired 4G ethernet gateway later this week which will give us reasonable bandwidth (at expense) until the FTTP is completed.

I can’t really set my MX and other DNS records to the 4G IP address and  I doubt they’d allow port 25 and others through inwards - and in any case I've no doubt the public IP address of a mobile 4G connection will not be on the "Ok to send email" list so all the company's sent mail would get binned by everyone.

I am aware of public IP address SIMs. These are extremely expensive, but will be used as a last resort.

**TL;DR;**

Is it possible to hire a public IP address and firewall somewhere (AWS) such that one of my machines can VPN into it – and then I can set my DNS records to point to the public IP address and have the NAT functions of either the firewall at the public IP address (or build another routing table within my network here) – and from there my mail server should work ok – albeit through the VPN tunnel.

**update & rephrasing**
As requested by another user:
I have a network with a bunch of servers on it. We, temporarily, have lost out primary internet connection. 
What’s the best way to make use of a 4G network connection to allow outbound mail and inbound connections including mail and https amongst others.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to help, but your question is really quite confusing. It's generally better to give us your situation and problem, rather than asking "will this solution I've come up with work", that way we can think about the best way to achieve it. Can you perhaps edit your question and add a section along the lines of "I have a physical server in location X with connectivity Y. The problem I'm having is Z (which may be technical or physical). What's the best way to achieve this?"

Comment: I’ve added an update as requested.

Comment: `The physical machine and its associated services are still at the old office making use of the internet there.` - For how long? Is it possible to leave it there until the new office internet connection is in place?

Comment: Wouldn't literally any cheap virtual server somewhere suffice? Install an SMTP relay server there that is configured to accept email from your office and forward it to the outside world, and vice-versa.
If your 4G IP is not static, use either dynamic DNS services, or establish a simple SSH tunnel - no need for VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **mail relay** in AWS that will:

- be in your MX DNS record
- receive incoming email from outside on behalf of your domain
- forward the email to your Exchange, either direct (if there is direct connectivity) or over a VPN
- receive outgoing email from Exchange and relay it to the recipients on the internet from a *good* ip address

The mail relay can be a simple EC2 instance with Linux and Postfix, or if you prefer Windows + some email relay solution (I'm not a windows expert, sorry).

Anyway the keywords to look up are **mail relay**.

Hope that helps :)